# Python: MySQL-Query fails

Tags: python, mysql, debugging

In general, I am familiar with MySQL but not with Python.
I try to generate .py script which inserts an user with a hashed password into a mysql-database of the radius-server.

That's my script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import sys
import MySQLdb
from passlib.hash import django_pbkdf2_sha256 as cryptohandler


def adduser(username, password_plain):
    password = cryptohandler.encrypt(password_plain)

    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="radius", passwd="radpass", db="radius")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    if cursor.execute("SELECT op FROM radcheck WHERE username = %s", (username)):
        print 'FEHLER: User existiert bereits und kann daher nicht angelegt werden.'
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        try:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO radcheck(username, attribute, op, value) VALUES(%s, 'Password', ':=', %s)", (username, password))
            conn.commit()
            print 'OK user '+ username +' successfully added with hash'+ password
            sys.exit(0)
        except:
            conn.rollback()
            print 'FEHLER query failed'
            sys.exit(1)

def main():
    adduser(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])


main()
```

The output is always "FEHLER query failed", the first query which looks up if an username is existing works fine.

The radcheck table:

```
id int(11) unsigned Null=No Key=Pri Default=Null Extra=auto_increment
username varchar(64) Null=No Key=Mul
attribute varchar(64) Null=No
op char(2) Null=No Default="=="
value varchar(253) Null=No
```

Executing the query in the mysql-command-line works fine.

Where is the error in my script?
I thought it may be a too long hash, but the hash is only < 100 chars long. (But contains special characters such as the dollar $).
Additionally I'd appreciate help how to debug python-sql-scripts in general!

Comment: I selected all records from the database and actually, these records are stored. But why do I get an exception?

Comment: To get more information, change your `except` to `except Exception as e:`. Then change `print 'FEHLER query failed'` to `print e`

Comment: Interestingly, my last comment will resolve your issue but does little to reveal what was happening behind the scenes and causing you pain. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not your MySQL code but it is this try/except block:

```
try:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO radcheck(username, attribute, op, value) VALUES(%s, 'Password', ':=', %s)", (username, password))
    conn.commit()
    print 'OK user '+ username +' successfully added with hash'+ password
    sys.exit(0)
except:
    conn.rollback()
    print 'FEHLER query failed'
    sys.exit(1)
```

When you call `sys.exit(0)`, it raises an exception called `SystemExit`. Since a bare `except:` catch statement catches `SystemExit`, this block will always be executed when you call `sys.exit(0)`. To prevent this from happening, change your `except:` catch to:

```
except Exception as e:
    conn.rollback()
    print 'FEHLER query failed'
    sys.exit(1)
```

Even better is if you catch only MySQL errors with:

```
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    conn.rollback()
    print 'FEHLER query failed'
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know that sys.exit() raises an exeption. I thought the script just terminates and returns 0 to the process which called the python script.

I didn't tried it yet, but if I take the "except Exception as e:" block, why is the raised SystemExit exception not catched there?

Comment: Because `SystemExit` is not derived form `Exception`. `Exception` is, in general, a base class that users and module writers extend with their own code. For more information, see the official documentation for [Exception](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.Exception) and [SystemExit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit)

Comment: That's interestion, then I do understand the logic behind. I thought each exception in Python is derived from `exception`. Good to know that.
I used the last solution you provided and it works fine for me. Thanks! :)